# Scala: convert map to case class

Tags: scala

Let's say I have this example case class

```
case class Test(key1: Int, key2: String, key3: String)
```

And I have a map

```
myMap = Map("k1" -> 1, "k2" -> "val2", "k3" -> "val3")
```

I need to convert this map to my case class in several places of the code, something like this:

```
myMap.asInstanceOf[Test]
```

What would be the easiest way of doing that? Can I somehow use implicit for this?

Comment: I don't understand why the answers are so complex.  How about a normal function `def map2Test(m: Map[String, Any]) = Test(m("k1').asInstanceOf[Int], m("k2") ... )`  If you want an abstraction that converts maps to any case class, you probably have to use reflection.

Comment: @RobN: The point is to avoid reflection. You say the answers are complex, I say your answer is fragile.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049985/how-to-convert-generic-potentially-nested-mapstring-any-to-case-class-using-a/55050038

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Two ways of doing this elegantly. The first is to use an `unapply`, the second to use an implicit class (2.10+) with a type class to do the conversion for you.

1) The unapply is the simplest and most straight forward way to write such a conversion. It does not do any "magic" and can readily be found if using an IDE. Do note, doing this sort of thing can clutter your companion object and cause your code to sprout dependencies in places you might not want:

```
object MyClass{
  def unapply(values: Map[String,String]) = try{
    Some(MyClass(values("key").toInteger, values("next").toFloat))
  } catch{
    case NonFatal(ex) => None
  }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
val MyClass(myInstance) = myMap
```

be careful, as it would throw an exception if not matched completely.

2) Doing an implicit class with a type class creates more boilerplate for you but also allows a lot of room to expand the same pattern to apply to other case classes:

```
implicit class Map2Class(values: Map[String,String]){
  def convert[A](implicit mapper: MapConvert[A]) = mapper conv (values)
}

trait MapConvert[A]{
  def conv(values: Map[String,String]): A
}
```

and as an example you'd do something like this:

```
object MyObject{
  implicit val new MapConvert[MyObject]{
    def conv(values: Map[String, String]) = MyObject(values("key").toInt, values("foo").toFloat)
  }
}
```

which could then be used just as you had described above:

```
val myInstance = myMap.convert[MyObject]
```

throwing an exception if no conversion could be made. Using this pattern converting between a `Map[String, String]` to any object would require just another implicit (and that implicit to be in scope.)

Comment: @flavian true but I believe he would want the exception as not converting is an unexpected result at the point where it was invoked. At least, I would want the exception.

Comment: the `object MyObject { ... }` code doesn't compile for me

Comment: @wheaties Presuming `MyClass` is a case class with companion Object, shouldn't your `unapply` approach require the object to have a different name [since there's already a defined `unapply` method by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850088/1080804)? For instance, I could only get something like this to compile: `val MyClassOfMap(myInstance) = myMap`

Comment: @ecoe you can `override` if you need to do so. Or, I should say, you once could do so. This question and answer are now 5yrs old!

Comment: @wheaties I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to understand why you used `unapply` and not `apply` in the first solution. Scala docs say [Whereas the apply method is like a constructor which takes arguments and creates an object, the unapply takes an object and tries to give back the arguments.](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html). Since we're converting arguments (the Map) to the object (MyClass), shouldn't `apply` be used?

Answer (score 18):

Here is an alternative non-boilerplate method that uses Scala reflection (Scala 2.10 and above) and doesn't require a separately compiled module:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class Test(t: String, ot: Option[String])

package object ccFromMap {
  def fromMap[T: TypeTag: ClassTag](m: Map[String,_]) = {
    val rm = runtimeMirror(classTag[T].runtimeClass.getClassLoader)
    val classTest = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
    val classMirror = rm.reflectClass(classTest)
    val constructor = typeOf[T].decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructor)

    val constructorArgs = constructor.paramLists.flatten.map( (param: Symbol) => {
      val paramName = param.name.toString
      if(param.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Option[Any]])
        m.get(paramName)
      else
        m.get(paramName).getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map is missing required parameter named " + paramName))
    })

    constructorMirror(constructorArgs:_*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}

class CaseClassFromMapSpec extends Specification {
  "case class" should {
    "be constructable from a Map" in {
      import ccFromMap._
      fromMap[Test](Map("t" -> "test", "ot" -> "test2")) === Test("test", Some("test2"))
      fromMap[Test](Map("t" -> "test")) === Test("test", None)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution.  One function works for any class, it doesn't require macros, doesn't require external dependencies, and uses all supported features.  Works like a charm for me.

Comment: One minor suggestion.  fromMap current returns Any.  Changing the last line to constructorMirror(constructorArgs:_*).asInstanceOf[T] makes it so it returns the correct type.

Comment: One other comment to be aware of.  If you have an Option[String] parameter to your case class, this code expects the Map to contain a String.  If it actually contains Option[String] you end up with a problem.  Removing the "if" statement changes this.  Depends on what you want.

Comment: @DaveDeCaprio Actually the solution using macros should be faster to execute as the "reflections" are made at compile time there, while this solution uses runtime reflection (notoriously slower than compile time)

Comment: Can you do it so it handles nested structures?

Answer (score 5):

Jonathan Chow implements a Scala macro (designed for Scala 2.11) that generalizes this behavior and eliminates the boilerplate.

http://blog.echo.sh/post/65955606729/exploring-scala-macros-map-to-case-class-conversion

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

trait Mappable[T] {
  def toMap(t: T): Map[String, Any]
  def fromMap(map: Map[String, Any]): T
}

object Mappable {
  implicit def materializeMappable[T]: Mappable[T] = macro materializeMappableImpl[T]

  def materializeMappableImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Mappable[T]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
    val companion = tpe.typeSymbol.companionSymbol

    val fields = tpe.declarations.collectFirst {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isPrimaryConstructor ⇒ m
    }.get.paramss.head

    val (toMapParams, fromMapParams) = fields.map { field ⇒
      val name = field.name
      val decoded = name.decoded
      val returnType = tpe.declaration(name).typeSignature

      (q"$decoded → t.$name", q"map($decoded).asInstanceOf[$returnType]")
    }.unzip

    c.Expr[Mappable[T]] { q"""
      new Mappable[$tpe] {
        def toMap(t: $tpe): Map[String, Any] = Map(..$toMapParams)
        def fromMap(map: Map[String, Any]): $tpe = $companion(..$fromMapParams)
      }
    """ }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works well for me，if you use jackson for scala：

```
def from[T](map: Map[String, Any])(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.convertValue(map)
}
```

Reference from：[Convert a Map<String, String> to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

Comment: could Circe able to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't love this code, but I suppose this is possible if you can get the map values into a tuple and then use the `tupled` constructor for your case class.  That would look something like this:

```
val myMap = Map("k1" -> 1, "k2" -> "val2", "k3" -> "val3")    
val params = Some(myMap.map(_._2).toList).flatMap{
  case List(a:Int,b:String,c:String) => Some((a,b,c))
  case other => None
}    
val myCaseClass = params.map(Test.tupled(_))
println(myCaseClass)
```

You have to be careful to make sure the list of values is exactly 3 elements and that they are the correct types.  If not, you end up with a None instead.  Like I said, not great, but it shows that it is possible.

Comment: For this solution, I would only replace the ```myMap.map(_._2)``` by ```myMap.values```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an update to Jonathon's answer for Scala 3 (which no longer has TypeTag). Be aware that this won't work for case classes nested inside of other classes. But for top-level case classes it seems to work fine.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Reflect:

  def fromMap[T <: Product : ClassTag](m: Map[String, ?]): T = 

    val classTag = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
    val constructor = classTag.runtimeClass.getDeclaredConstructors.head
    val constructorArgs = constructor.getParameters()
      .map { param =>
        val paramName = param.getName
        if (param.getType == classOf[Option[_]])
          m.get(paramName)
        else
          m.get(paramName)
            .getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Missing required parameter: $paramName"))
      }
    constructor.newInstance(constructorArgs: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
```

And a test for the above:

```
case class Foo(a: String, b: Int, c: Option[String] = None)
case class Bar(a: String, b: Int, c: Option[Foo])

class ReflectSuite extends munit.FunSuite:

  test("fromMap") {
    
    val m = Map("a" -> "hello", "b" -> 42, "c" -> "world")
    val foo = Reflect.fromMap[Foo](m)
    assertEquals(foo, Foo("hello", 42, Some("world")))

    val n = Map("a" -> "hello", "b" -> 43)
    val foo2 = Reflect.fromMap[Foo](n)
    assertEquals(foo2, Foo("hello", 43))

    val o = Map("a" -> "yo", "b" -> 44, "c" -> foo)
    val bar = Reflect.fromMap[Bar](o)
    assertEquals(bar, Bar("yo", 44, Some(foo)))
  }

  test("fromMap should fail when required parameter is missing") {
    val m = Map("a" -> "hello", "c" -> "world")
    intercept[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] {
      Reflect.fromMap[Foo](m)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
commons.mapper.Mappers.mapToBean[CaseClassBean](map)
```

Details: https://github.com/hank-whu/common4s