# Generate Case Class from Map[String, Type]?

Tags: scala, code-generation, shapeless

Given a function `f`, that, given a `Map[String, MyType]`, returns a `HList`:

```
package net

import shapeless._

sealed trait MyType
case object MyInt extends MyType
case object MyStr extends MyType

object Mapper {

    def f(m: Map[String, MyType]): HList = m.foldLeft[HList](HNil){ (acc, elem) =>
        val (key, t) = elem
        t match {
            case MyInt => classOf[Int] :: acc
            case MyStr => classOf[String] :: acc
        } 
    }
}
```

I tested it:

```
import net._
val list = Map("foo" -> MyInt, "bar" -> MyStr)

scala> Mapper.f(list)
res0: shapeless.HList = class java.lang.String :: int :: HNil
```

How can I use the above approach (or another one) to build a `case class` with members matching the `String` keys, and the types given by the output of `f`?

So, I'm looking for:

`g(Map("foo" -> MyInt, "bar" -> MyStr))` to output `case class X(foo: Int, bar: String)` where `X` is arbitrarily chosen, i.e. not important at this point.

I thought of using `Generic[X]`, but I don't know how to get a `Generic` without a `case class` first.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684572/scala-convert-map-to-case-class

Comment: I don't believe it's a dupe since I am trying to produce a case class. The other answer already provides one, as I see it.

Comment: Ah I see, hm using a `String` to create a variable name could possibly require some advanced reflection, I can imagine a macro function could do it, but others may be able to point you to a third-party solution. I may take a stab at the macro solution if nothing else comes up.

Comment: 99.9% of the time `HList` is useless as a static type. You could have something like a function taking a map (optionally) into an extensible record, but you'd still need to specify the record type statically.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're trying to do can't happen in Scala with compile time verification. The issue here is exactly as you've elaborated, you don't have the definition of the `case class` you're trying to build in advance. That definition provides the scaffolding to use a `Record` type to construct the isomorphism.

That said, we might be able to work something with invoke dynamic and reflection but I'm unclear on how you'd even take advantage of that in code. You wouldn't know the field names in advance nor their types. So how would you even write code around them?