# How to create a scala case class instance with a Map instance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a scala case class whose fields come form a map . And , here is the case class

```
 case class UserFeature(uid: String = null,
                     age: String = null,
                     marriageStatus: String = null,
                     consumptionAbility: String = null,
                     LBS: String = null,
                     interest1: String = null,
                     interest2: String = null,
                     interest3: String = null,
                     interest4: String = null,
                     interest5: String = null,
                     kw1: String = null,
                     kw2: String = null,
                     kw3: String = null,
                     topic1: String = null,
                     topic2: String = null,
                     topic3: String = null,
                     appIdInstall: String = null,
                     appIdAction: String = null,
                     ct: String = null,
                     os: String = null,
                     carrier: String = null,
                     house: String = null
                          )
```

suppose the map instance is

```
Map("uid" -> "4564131",
    "age" -> "5",
    "ct" -> "bk7755")
```

how can I apply the keys&values of the map to the fields&values of case class?

Comment: I suppose the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684572/scala-convert-map-to-case-class.

Comment: Oh ,that's pretty nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do `UserFeature(uid = map_var("uid"), age = map_var("age"), ct = map_var("ct"))` assuming the variable holding `Map` is `map_var` and the keys are available

Comment: Thank you for the answer,but , am I right in thinking the map_var("ct") may give the value of the field "marriageStatus"?

Comment: That is just extracting value. You can pass it in any position required together with other parameters or you may not use it if it's not required

Comment: How the class know the value in map_var("ct") is the value of the field "ct"

Comment: That is extracting value from a key. map_var(''ct) will return "bk7755". You may not use it if not required

Comment: How the class know  "bk7755" is the value of the field "ct" instead of the field "marriageStatus" .And , is the compiler parse the parameter by order?

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your questions. All that happens here is, value from map is extracted and are passed to case class. I've assumed that value of 'ct' is marriageStatus. If that's not the case, you may not use it. I was only showing how to extract value from map and pass it as a parameter to case class.

Comment: @pms The problem with your answer is that you have assigned `map_var("ct")` to the `marriageStatus` field, when it should be in the `ct` field.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use `null` to represent missing string values. Use `Option[String]` instead.

```
case class UserFeature(uid: Option[String] = None,
                       age: Option[String] = None,
                       marriageStatus: Option[String] = None,
                       ...
```

Once you have done that, you can use `get` on the map to retrieve the value.

```
UserFeature(map.get("uid"), map.get("age"), map.get("marriageStatus") ...)
```

Values that are present in the map will be `Some(value)` and missing values will be `None`. The `Option` class has lots of useful methods for processing optional values in a safe way.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation on Option[String],do you have github or something I can fellow?

Comment: @SteveYN Happy to help, but I don't have a github presence or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Synthesizing the other two answers, I would convert all the `String`s in `UserFeature` that you're defaulting to `null` (which you should basically never use in Scala unless interacting with poorly-written Java code requires it, and even then use it as little as possible) to `Option[String]`.  I leave that search-and-replace out of the answer.

Then you can do:

```
object UserFeature {
  def apply(map: Map[String, String]): UserFeature =
    UserFeature(map.get("uid"), map.get("age") ...)
}
```

Which lets you use:

```
val someMap: Map[String, String] = ...
val userFeature = UserFeature(someMap)
```

With the change to `Option[String]`, there will be some other changes that need to be made in your codebase.  https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html is a good tutorial for how to deal with Option.