# Issue while converting Scala Map to Object on Databricks Notebook

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, databricks

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzVTA.png)

I have a scenario where I need to convert a scala Map to a case class object and with help of the following references I was able to achieve it locally (scala version 2.12.13):

1. [Scala: convert map to case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684572/scala-convert-map-to-case-class)
2. [Convert a Map into Scala object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698667/convert-a-map-into-scala-object/68698709#68698709)

But when I tried running the same block of code in Databricks notebook it throws an error:

`IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of '$line23851bc084ae4df7a16bf9c475868d9265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Test' (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]`

Cluster configuration: Databricks runtime 8.2(Includes Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12). Please refer to the screenshot for the complete code.

**Workaround (not advisable)**:

```
def workaround(map: Map[String, Any]): Test = {
  Test(
    map("k1").asInstanceOf[Int],
    map("k2").asInstanceOf[String],
    map("k3").asInstanceOf[String],
  )
}

val result = workaround(myMap)
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This smells to me like one of two possibilities.

First, we should double check that there is no version mis-matching between something in your local runtime environment and the databricks runtime environment. You can check [this page](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/8.2.html#installed-java-and-scala-libraries-scala-212-cluster-version) for a list of all library versions included in DBR 8.2. In particular, I would check your local environment to make sure you are running the same version of jackson (2.10.0).

Second, this could be an interaction between how Databricks implements their notebook and a limitation of jackson. Each command of a databricks notebooks is wrapped in a [package object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/package-objects.html) that is given a random name. For example, I can tell from the exception that the package object which holds your `Test` class definition *was* called `$line23851bc084ae4df7a16bf9c475868d9265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw`. (I say that it *was* named that because each time you re-run the command it will generate a new package object). This implies that all classes (and other kinds of type definitions) are actually [path dependent types](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/path-dependent-types#2-inner-classes-and-path-dependent-types) when put inside a notebook. More specifically for this scenario, your `Test` class is an inner-class to the package object. based on the error message and some brief reading of docs, I suspect that Jackson cannot serialize path dependent types.